# Python - referencing dataframe column using str() instead of quotations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is a function that calculates the conjunctive probability of country flags in a sample containing a specific colour. It is from a DataQuest exercise. It only asks for the probability of three flags containing red but I wanted to challenge myself and write a function for n and colour.

Flags is a dataframe. There are colour columns. 1 if the colour is there, 0 if it is not.

```
import numpy as np

def conjunctive_probability(n, colour):
    total_count = flags.shape[0]
    colour_picked = flags[flags[str(colour)] == 1].shape[0]
    p = 0
    probabilities = []

    for p in range(n):
        probability = colour_picked / total_count
        probabilities.append(probability)
        colour_picked -= 1
        total_count -= 1
        p += 1
    return np.prod(np.array(probabilities))

three_red = conjunctive_probability(3, red)
```

I get an error on line 5 (colour_picked). If I type in a colour there, such as:

```
colour_picked = flags[flags['red'] == 1].shape[0]
```

it works.

But I don't understand why str() doesn't work. It gives me:

```
KeyError: '153'
```

which is the number of flags that have the colour red.

Answer (score 0):

The `str()` isn't the problem. The key error likely indicates that `flags[YOUR_KEY]` does not exist. In the specific error, `flags[153]` does not exist, meaning `153` is not a key in your `flags` dict. I do not see where `flags` is initialized in your post.

Comment: I don't use flags[153]. All I did was add another argument (colour) to the function. So instead of (n), it is now (n, colour). If I had flags['red'], and calling it with conjunctive_probability(3) it works fine. But having flags[str(colour)], then calling the function conjunctive_probability(3, red) gives an error. EDIT: Just tried it again and it's giving me NameError: name 'red' is not defined, on the last line. EDIT #2: I just called the function with quotations around 'red'. That worked. I don't understand why str() in the function doesn't work though.

Comment: you are getting a Key Error. This is an error thrown when you try to get a key from a dictionary but the key is not there. I do not think your `str()` is throwing this error. I think the value you're trying to index into flags is not what you expect.